# Is DistUtilsExtra EOL?

Tags: package-management, python, snap

Has python-distutils-extra effectively been EOLed?

1. Snapcraft doesn't support them, so currently it's not possible to make a snap out of a python program that uses python-distutils-extra in its setup.py.
2. The developers working on [python packaging](https://packaging.python.org/) don't support it.
3. I'm not aware of any proper documentation for it.

Unfortunately, I'm also not aware of an alternative to python-distutils-extra.

Answer (score 2):

[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-distutils-extra) seems to think not. There are sources for 17.10, 17.04, 16.04. What I do see is that it moved from MAIN to UNIVERSE so something did happen.

Another approach to installing python modules is through PIP or Conda.

```
conda install -c anaconda-cluster python-distutils-extra=2.40
pip install http://launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/trunk/2.40/+download/python-distutils-extra-2.40.tar.gz
```

Either would install version 2.40 (untested so comment if any of these show errors).

Comment: Launchpad shows its almost total lack of development in the last few years, hence my question. Pip is developed by the python packaging developers I linked to in the question. Snapcraft supports pip. Conda is for use by the scientific community.